# Material for stud cavity cold air return

Tags: hvac, ducts

I'm totally aware of the arguments for and against stud cavity air returns so I don't need opinions on that, but I do need an idea of the best material for lining the outside of the stud cavity with. Is sheet metal the only option or is there something else you can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thermopan and similar material is a good alternative to sheet metal joist lining. It seals better and doesn't tin can like metal joist lining.

![enter image description here]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Yw1.jpg)

http://www.thermopan.com/

It's ba fire rated cardboard but it works well.